# Photoshop Automate Batch - Destination folder (use)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

In Photoshop- I am running a Batch Action over a folder of PNG files.  It opens the PNG makes a selection over some existing text deletes it and writes some other text.

Originally in the action I had a step which exported the PNG file to the new folder.  I tinkered with it a little bit and deleted the export step out of the action.  I found that by just using the Automate Batch dialog window and setting the Destination folder as the folder that the open PNG file was just automatically saved into the detstination folder as a PNG.  Hence why I could remove the Export step.

I have 2 questions:

1. The export step was taking 4 to 5 seconds and now as part of the Automatic batch it is only taking around 1 second to save it.  Why is the time taken so different?
2. Is it saving as a PNG because the orignial file is a PNG or is it becuase my default export settings is set to PNG?

Thanks for any answers here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Depends on the type of export your Action had. If it was `Save For Web`, then yes, it's generally 3-4 times slower than `Save As`
2. Yep, Batch uses active document extension to determine file type it's going to save.